# How can I get Seahorse Passwords and Keys to read-in passwords from $HOME/.gnupg?

Tags: password, seahorse

After reinstalling my system, I copied the .gnupg folder from backup into my new home folder.

Unfortunately, Seahorse does not read-in the passwords from that folder.

It does pick-up the ssh keys from the .ssh folder and the certificate keys from .gnupg.

With a previous reinstall, it did pick-up the passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seahorse does not read the passwords from **$HOME/.gnupg**, but from **$HOME/.gnome2/keyrings**.